# Can't get wordpress ajax form to submit

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am porting an application to WordPress. It uses a form to select what attributes the customer is looking for in an Adult Family Home via checkboxes and drop-downs. It re-searches the database on each onchange and keyup. Originally I had the application standalone in PHP, but when I migrated it to WordPress I started having issues.

Currently in WP I have the code conditionalized ($DavesWay == 1) to do ajax the normal no-WordPress-way and ($DavesWay == 0) to do it the WordPress-way.

In the non-WordPress-way, the ajax works fine EXCEPT that I get a WP header and menu between the search form and the results-div that Ajax puts the data in. I get no errors from WP or in the JS console. In the WP-way The search form displayed, but nothing happens when I check any of the checkboxes. The JS console displays

POST http://localhost/demo4/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

But I don't see any way to tell exactly what it is complaining about. How should I troubleshoot this?

Troubleshooting = Examine the HTML output, lots of echos and exits in PHP code, look at JS console.

```js
function submitPg1(theForm) {
        // Used with onChange from "most" form elements, but not on those that change the page
        // rather than the select criteria. Such as rowsPerPage, pageNumber etc.
        setById("pageNo", "1"); // set inital page
        mySubmit();
    }

    function mySubmit(theForm) { // The actual ajax submit
        // DO NOT set page number
            jQuery.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: jQuery("#asi_search_form").serialize(),       // get the form data
            type: jQuery("#asi_search_form").attr("method"),    // GET or POST
            url:  jQuery("#asi_search_form").attr("action"),    // the file to call
            success: function (response) {                      // on success..
                jQuery("#result").html(response);               // update the DIV
            }
        })
    }

    function setById(id, value) { // Used to set vales by Id
        x = document.getElementById(id).value;
        x.value = value;
    }

    // 1st submit with blank selection
    jQuery(document).ready(function () { submitPg1(this.form) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Code fragments: (from the displayed page source)

<div id="asi_container" class="asi_container" >
        <noscript><h2>This site requires Javascript and cookies to function. See the Help page for how to enable them.</h2></noscript>
        <div id="searchForm">
            <form id="asi_search_form" name="asi_search_form" method="post"  action="http://localhost/demo4/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"> 
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="asi_LTCfetchAll_ajax" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">
                        <table id="greenTable" class="asi_table" title="The Green areas are for site administration, not typical users">
                        <tbody>
```

```html
PHP code:

$DavesWay = 0; 
if ($DavesWay == 1){  //echo "Daves Way Setup"; // Dave's way, which works but prints the menu twice
    if( $operation == "submit"){ 
        require("asi_LTCfetchAll.php"); // for each onchange or onkeyup
    }else{
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'asi_tc_admin', '12' ); // Initial page refresh # must be >12
    }
}else{
    // The WordPress way that I could't get to work -- asi_LTCfetch never gets called 
    function asi_LTCfetchAll_ajax(){
        //echo "<br /> Goto to Submit function";   // DEBUG
        require($asi_plugin_dir . "/includes" . '/asi_LTCfetchAll.php');
    }

    add_action( "wp_ajax_asi_LTCfetchAll_ajax", "asi_LTCfetchAll_ajax" );          // admin users
    add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_asi_LTCfetchAll_ajax", "asi_LTCfetchAll_ajax" );   // non-logged in users
    add_filter( "the_content", "asi_tc_admin", "12" );                      // Initial page refresh # must be >12
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the endpoint using a rest-client like Postman? Your PHP code looks a bit strange. You're defining a function inside an else statement?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the JavaScript to the way WordPress recommends it in [their documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins):

```
var data = {
    'action': 'my_action',
    'whatever': 1234
};

jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying following URL: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Also you can use the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-lite/

Comment: Please put information in your answer, rather than links to other sites. Those can disappear if the site gets reorganized.

Comment: Sure, but those are the official links from codex and WordPress.